# Is it possible to edit YML file from a seperate admin portal for static web development HUGO theme?

Tags: yaml, hugo

I have a hugo theme website and i want to make an admin portal to edit the contents of the website which are all located in the data/homepage.yml file.

Is there a way to keep my website a static website and still have an admin portal to update the contents like the phrases and stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that, but your question is very generic, so I can only give you some broad guidelines.

1. Check out the [Frontend Interfaces with Hugo](https://gohugo.io/tools/frontends/) page on their documentation site. This is a list of services or programs to help manage your Hugo site.
2. If you're version controlling using `git`, and hosting the code on something like GitHub, you could look into the in-browser editors they provide. Making the repository private, and restricted to only the admins means that you've got editor authentication covered.

Some other constraints for you to consider in your search:

- do you need this to be available online / through the Internet? Or does it suffice to have a program on someone's computer?
- how many users editing the content are there?
- how tech-savyy are they? Do they know how to edit the raw Markdown / yaml files or do they need a WSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a Front End interface allowing to update the content of your website, without having to dig on the markdown files.

There are several resources in the Hugo documentation that could allow you to achieve what you want. Have a look at this page:

https://gohugo.io/tools/frontends/